# Como fazer para ver se já existe um registo na base de dados mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde comunidade,

Ando neste momento a rever alguns conceitos de html, php, css, mysql, e fui construindo um simples sistema de login com um formulário de registo, através de alguns videos.
Até aqui tudo bem, tirando o momento em que consegui registar dois clientes com o mesmo username. Passei algumas horas em pesquisas e tentei alterar o meu código, mas nunca consegui construir uma função para verificar se já existe um cliente com o mesmo nome na base de dados.

Se alguém me poder indicar o bom caminho para eu conseguir a verificação, fico agradecido.

Este é o código que trata tudo referente ao servidor:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();
    //liga à base de dados
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "mobies");
        //se o botão de registar for clicado
        if (isset($_POST['register'])){
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password_1']);
            $password_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password_2']);
            //faz com que os espaços estejam bem preenchidos
            if (empty($username)){
                array_push($errors, "Username is required");
            }
            if (empty($email)){
                array_push($errors, "Email is required");
            }
            if (empty($password_1)){
                array_push($errors, "Password is required");
            }
            if ($password_1 != $password_2){
                array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
            }
            //se não houver erros, salva o novo utilizador na base de dados
            if (count($errors) == 0) {
                $password = md5($password_1);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
                mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }
//login através do formulário de login
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    //faz com que os espaços estejam bem preenchidos
    if (empty($username)){
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)){
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
//logout
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header('location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Obrigado :)

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja certa, por favor não se esqueça de marcar como correta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dê um `UNIQUE` na coluna, assim irá prevenir que o MySQL tenha duas informações iguais naquela coluna, exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE utilizadores ADD UNIQUE (email)
```

Isso irá fazer o `email` ser único, ou seja não pode ter dois e-mails iguais.

---

Então faça:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO ...");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) === 1){
    // Deu certo
}
```

Toda responsabilidade de prevenir uma duplicação será do MySQL. Se tentar inserir um dado já existente ele não será inserido, logo `mysqli_affected_rows` será de `0`.

---

Uma outra maneira, sem utilizar o `UNIQUE` seria fazer um SELECT de depois um INSERT:

```
$evitaDuplicacao = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `` FROM ... WHERE email = '$email'") 

if(mysqli_num_rows($evitaDuplicacao) === 0){
   // Não existe um dado repetido, logo:
   mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO ...");
}
```

Cada um tem uma vantagem, em geral prefiro o primeiro, usando UNIQUE. O segundo método está exposto a um [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) e esta solução existe a execução de duas queries distintas. Entretanto o uso do UNIQUE em tabelas grandes pode tornar o processo de inserção mais lento, por motivos óbvios. Enfim, escolha um.

---

*No demais, o PHP tem suporte para o `password_hash` (BCrypt e futuramente Argon2i), bem como o `hash_pbkdf2` ambas são extremamente facieis de serem implementadas, tanto quanto o `md5()`. Além de já ter o [Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php), que suporta o Argon2i e o SCrypt. Não há motivos para usar algo considerado quebrado desde [1994](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/acmccs94.pdf) como o MD5, [veja isto](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/), [isto](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) e [talvez isto](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).*

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Neste meu caso, usei o método UNIQUE e acrescentei mais umas linhas de código e resolve perfeitamente o meu problema, muito obrigado.


//verifica se já existe um utilizador com o mesmo username na base de dados
$evitaDuplicacao = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '$username'");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) !== 0){
array_push($errors, "User already exists");
}